# Bar chart or histogram for frequency of features in one week bins in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a data frame as seen below (three columns are shown here):

```
Week/Year  feature
40/2017    2          147
           3           32
           4           21
           5           21
           7            8
           8            1
           9           10
           10          10
           11           8
           12          23
           14           3
           15          10
           16           3
           17           4
           18          15
           19          10
           21          19
           22          12
           23           3
           24           8
           26           3
           27          47
           28           8
           29           6
           30          11
           31          11
           34           7
           35           8
           36           9
           38          21
                     ... 
51/2017    40           7
           43           2
           44           1
           45           3
           46           1
           47           1
           51           2
           58           1
           62           3
           63           2
           64           1
           66           3
           67           1
           71           3
           72           3
           76           4
           77           5
           79           5
           81           1
           82           4
           85           3
           86           1
           87           1
           88           2
           89           1
           90           1
           93           4
           95           1
           96           3
           100          2
```

The third column shows the frequency of each feature for a week. I calculated the third column by this code:

```
df['Week/Year'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: "%d/%d" % (x.week, x.year))
```

I want to plot a histogram or bar chart that for each week of the year, plots frequency of each feature with different colors. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
df.plot(x = 'Week/Year', y = df.groupby(['Week/Year', 'feature']).size(), kind ='bar')
```

Thanks.

Comment: df.unstack().plot()

Comment: df.unstack.plot() gives me TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're getting **"TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot"** because the return of your lambda function is a string. You have two options, you convert your column only for plotting reasons or rewrite your lambda function to return a numeric value (float or int).

Comment: But, my x is categorical, and I get the size for y

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Do you mind trying the following code:
df.groupby(['Week/Year', 'feature']).size().plot(x='Week/Year', kind ='bar')

Comment: I think you forgot unstack() and it should be: df.groupby(['Week/Year', 'feature']).size()..unstack().plot(x='Week/Year', kind ='bar'). It worekd after I included unstack(). Thanks

Comment: if I want to divide each size by sum of all counts in a week, how should I do it?